# Wordpress how do I echo SUM from a column of a MySQL table by user id AND type_operation

Tags: plugin-development, customization, database, mysql

I have account funds table in wordpress database. Structure like this;

```
Id           user_id         fund_user        type_operation
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             1379               100              admin_op
2             1565               500              admin_op
3             1379              -50               pay
4             1379               200              admin_op
5             1616              -150              pay
```

And in my Wordpress page, I want to display the following:

**Loggedin user**'s only **admin_op** in *type_operation*, GET TOTAL only **positive** *fund_user* values.

I have this;

```
global $wpdb; 
$result_good = $wpdb->get_results("Select sum(fund_user) as good_points from wp_ywf_user_fund_log where type_operation='admin_op'");

        $haha= "Total Points for Good =".$result_good['good_points'];
        echo $haha;
        return $haha;
```

but that result none and i cant edit that for my specific query.

How can i get and echo in that table, for current user, specific type_operation's **Total** of fund_user's value?
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: [`wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) returns an array of row data (each is an object by default), so try with `$result_good[0]->good_points` or use [`wpdb::get_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/) to retrieve a single result.

Answer (score 0):

If it's no extricly neccesary perform an operation in a sql statement I would prefere perfom it over an Array of admin_op data, like :  op_sum = get_results( Select fund_user FROM table WHERE type_operation = admin_op ); then var = array_sum(op_sum);